# How to read audio file in dart flutter?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, mobile-application

In Python, It's possible to read an audio file as an array of samples and receive its sample rate with:

```
array_of_samples, samplerate = librosa.load('filename.mp3')
```

also:

```
array_of_samples, samplerate = sf.read('existing_file.wav')
```

Is there any similar way to do it in Dart code?